# Unit Testing Ignore owner from H2 database

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, h2

I would like to test multiple methods without having restrictions to access the database. There was legacy code which has the query coded and I was wondering if H2 can ignore those prefixes owner while testing.

For example:
in the code...

```
..
String q = "SELECT user FROM admin_dba.Empolyees where id < ? and id > 25";
try {
    con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);

            pst = con.prepareStatement(q);
            pst.setLong(1,  id);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
...
```

as for testing am I able to ignore that admin_dba in H2?

Comment: Are you testing against a database or running a simple unit test where you'd want all data access mocked out?

Comment: testing against a database. but the schema was redefined, we are not using the production database.

Comment: Would it be impossible to create a test schema/DB with the same name as the production schema? There probably is no way around that (without changing the query).

Comment: production we use oracle, for testing we use H2